# DelayHook Error for Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_32bit

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++, qt5, qt5.15

I have an error that pops up on the application output when I run a project which says:

```
[Error] DelayHook can't open TMUMH_DELAY_HOOKING_MUTEX, error code: 2
```

It keeps being printed on the application output every second or two.

As far as I can see, it does not affect the program anyway.

I tried creating two new projects, a fresh console project and a fresh Widgets project and run them without editing anything. They had the same error message printed on the output.

What could be the reason behind this Error Message?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/144001/delayhook-error-qt-6-4-3)?

Comment: I try that. I don't use Trend Micro Security. My mistake was caused after installing OpenCV. I suspect that it may be due to adjusting related environment variables, which resulted in constant errors.

Comment: After a minor Windows 10 update, QT started working normally again.